# H2O isolation forest -- scores greater than 1

Tags: h2o, outliers, unsupervised-learning

Isolation Forest in H2O (3.30.0.1, R 3.6.1) computed scores greater than 1 when model applied to the test set. Here is the code to reproduce scores greater than 1. Looks like h2o is not using the normalization used in the original paper [https://cs.nju.edu.cn/zhouzh/zhouzh.files/publication/icdm08b.pdf?q=isolation-forest] which is score=2^(-mean length/c(n)), c(n) is alway positive for n>0, so the scores should be always less than 1.

Other implementations of isolation forest produce scores less than 1 for the same data set.

Download [train](https://www.dropbox.com/s/sns4tbufaimetdd/train.csv?dl=0) and [test](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cmox8ugdjretjtk/test.csv?dl=0) data files.

```
library(data.table)
library(h2o)
h2o.init()
#import data
train<-h2o.importFile('train.csv')
test<-h2o.importFile('test.csv')
#Train model
model <- h2o.isolationForest(training_frame = train)
# Calculate score
scores <- h2o.predict(model,test)
max(scores[,1])
```

Comment: What is question here? Are you asking why scores are greater than 1?

Comment: My understanding from the original paper was that scores should be less than 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neema pointed out that h2o is using min/max path length to normalize which makes scores great than 1 possible.

[https://support.h2o.ai/support/tickets/97280]

Answer (score 0):

If your question is why the predicted value is greater than 1 for some rows in the test set, then this is due to the test values having shorter mean_lengths. I.e. fewer than average splits are needed to isolate them compared to training data. Remember that isolation forest uses an ensemble of trees (not just one). So if you have records more unique than training (anomalies), then your predicted value can be greater than 1 (or mean_length is shorter than normal).

You can see this by looking at the rows in your test data that have `predict` larger than 1:

`scores[scores[,1] > 1, ]`

```
   predict mean_length
1 1.232558        3.82
2 1.023256        4.36
3 1.069767        4.24
4 1.286822        3.68
```

Also, you can see that your training data had an mean_length averaged for all rows was 4.42 (which is larger than ones from your test data, mean_lengths above)

`scores_train <- h2o.predict(model,train)
mean(scores_train[,'mean_length'])`

```
4.42
```

Check out [this post](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/isolation-forest/interpreting_isolation-forest.ipynb) to learn more about interpreting isolation forests.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the notebook. I might be wrong, but looks like h2o is not using the normalization used in the original paper [https://cs.nju.edu.cn/zhouzh/zhouzh.files/publication/icdm08b.pdf?q=isolation-forest] which is score=2^(-mean length/c(n)), c(n) is alway positive for n>0, so the scores should be always less than 1.